# Get form ID and it's fields values dynamically from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Inside a table, I've created multiple forms using a loop based on data inside database.
Now I am not getting a way to implement a logic by which I wanted to identify of which form submit button is pressed so that I can update data accordingly in database.

What I did is putted an ID of that particular row as submit button id, but I am not getting how to put the same ID in javascript file (separate file) to fetch the field details, can someone help?

```
    <?php
    foreach ($get_subscribed_data as $filtered_items) { ?>
<tr>
    <form id="<?php echo $filtered_items->id; ?>" method="POST">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-group" id="user_account_name" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->user_account_name; ?>"><?php echo $filtered_items->user_account_name; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-group" id="user_project_name" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->user_project_name; ?>"><?php echo $filtered_items->user_project_name; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-group" id="start_date" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->start_date; ?>"><?php echo $filtered_items->start_date; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-group" id="due_date" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->due_date; ?>"><?php echo $filtered_items->due_date; ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="<?php echo $filtered_items->id; ?>" class="btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button></td>
    </tr></form>
    <?php } ?>
```

UPDATE:

jQuery code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.row-submit').on('click', e => {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();
        let $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            action: "send_modification_training_data",
          data: {
            user_account_name: $tr.find('.user_account_name').val(),
            user_project_name: $tr.find('.user_project_name').val(),
            start_date: $tr.find('.start_date').val(),
            due_date: $tr.find('.due_date').val(),
          },
          success: response => {
            console.log(response);
          } 
        });      
      });
 });
```

Comment: Since its a post form you can check for `if (isset($_POST['submit1'] {} ` or the likes and check which form is submitted that way. Also you don't seem to be closing the `form` tag.

Comment: @geertjanknapen thanks for the answer, I corrected the closing tag, but how will I identify the `submit1` you mentioned? As I am generating the multiple forms, so I am quite confused.

Comment: How are you sending the form data?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I am sending data using AJAX

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to begin with, you can not nest a form into a table like that. Either the form has to go around the whole table, or it needs to be contained within a single table cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you're using AJAX to send the form data, otherwise you wouldn't need to know which form was submit as the browser will collate the data for you.

To retrieve the data related to the clicked submit button you need to correct your HTML. Firstly, you need to remove all `id` attributes from the HTML you generate in the PHP loop as it will create duplicate values which is invalid, they must be unique. Change them to classes instead. Secondly, you cannot place a `form` element as a child of a `tr`.

In fact, given that you're using a `table` here you cannot use a `form` at all, as there's no way to make the HTML valid. You need to collate the `input` data on each row. To do this you can use `closest()` to find the `tr` related to the `button` and retrieve the `input` values using `find()`. Something like this:

```html
<?php foreach ($get_subscribed_data as $filtered_items) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-group user_account_name" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->user_account_name; ?>">
      <?php echo $filtered_items->user_account_name; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-group user_project_name" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->user_project_name; ?>">
      <?php echo $filtered_items->user_project_name; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-group start_date" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->start_date; ?>">
      <?php echo $filtered_items->start_date; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-group due_date" value="<?php echo $filtered_items->due_date; ?>">
      <?php echo $filtered_items->due_date; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm row-submit">Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

```js
$('.row-submit').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-handler.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      user_account_name: $tr.find('.user_account_name').val(),
      user_project_name: $tr.find('.user_project_name').val(),
      start_date: $tr.find('.start_date').val(),
      due_date: $tr.find('.due_date').val(),
    },
    success: response => {
      console.log(response);
    } 
  });      
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your code, but it's not working, even I tried `alert('test')` to check whether submit button is triggering javascript code or not but nothing happen when I click on submit button.

Comment: Sounds like you either have an error in the console from other code, haven't included jQuery in the page correctly or aren't running the JS after the DOM has loaded

Comment: I've added the jquery code in question, also as I checked in source code the jQuery file is getting loaded properly before my custom script.

Comment: Have you out it in a document.ready handler? I omitted it from my example as its use is always implied.

Comment: Yes you can check the code in question itself. I am using same classes you shared, also there is no error in console

Comment: FYI i am using datatables